# Mac Pro late 2013 Control Buttons?

Tags: mac, mac-pro

What is the **small slide button** located to the upper left of the main connection panel of the late 2013 Mac Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the **enclosure release**.

See: [Mac Pro (Late 2013) - Quick Start Guide](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1669/en_US/mac_pro_late-2013_gs.pdf%20.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Howdy Enigmatic: